# Share a single file in vagrant

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile

How do I share a single file, instead of sharing a whole folder like

```
config.vm.synced_folder "host/folder", "box/folder"
```

?

In other words is there a way to have something like:

```
config.vm.synced_folder "host/folder/file.conf", "box/folder/file.conf"
```

Comment: Why not share the whole folder? Or have a folder on the host containing just the one file?

Comment: There are already other files present in the location box/folder which I don't want to override. I only want to "override" the single file

Comment: @ydaetskcoR I also have the following case : I want to edit a `nginx.conf` config file, keep the config file in my repository but not import the whole folder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `include` flag in your rsync args array:

```
config.vm.synced_folder "host/folder/", "box/folder/", type: "rsync",
    rsync__args: ["--include=file.conf"]
```

Comment: include is not documented https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/synced-folders/rsync.html and it is not working

Answer (score 5):

The accepted answer (by cdmo) didn't work for me, but was close and led me to the right solution, so cheers. To copy just one file I needed to change it to:

```
config.vm.synced_folder "c:/hostpath/", "/guestpath/", type: "rsync",
  rsync__args: ["-r", "--include=file.text", "--exclude=*"]
```

Mind the arguments and their order, **-r** MUST be present and **--include** MUST precede **--exclude**.

If needed, instead of **-r** option you may use **-a** option which combines **-r** with several other options for preservation of permissions, ownership etc. (see rsync help).

My testing configuration: Vagrant 2.0.2/Win10/VirtualBox 5.2.6

Comment: Thanks for your answer, to elaborate on it - here is a better explanation of all of the options for rsync: https://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync

Comment: Please consider changing first line to:

````config.vm.synced_folder "/hostpath/", "/guestpath/", type: "rsync",````

not everybody is using Windows, and that could cause confusion

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [file](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/provisioning/file.html) provisioner to do this:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  # ... other configuration

  config.vm.provision "file", source: "~/.gitconfig", destination: ".gitconfig"
end
```

Comment: This doesn't keep the file synced, so it's not really "sharing." It's copying.

Comment: I would suggest changing the destination to "some/absolute/path/to/the/file" see if that works for someone, for now jedik's answer is hands down the best (well documented and it works)

Comment: @JosePaez the example as shown is straight from the document that was linked in my A'er. When I tried this back in 2017 it was working for me.

Answer (score 2):

You can't synchronize a single file. But maybe you can achieve the same effect by synchronizing the folder using [RSync](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/synced-folders/rsync.html) with the `rsync__exclude` option:

> `rsync__exclude` (string or array of strings) - A list of files or directories to exclude from the sync. The values can be any acceptable rsync exclude pattern.

Vagrant by default utilizes the file/folder synchronization mechanisms offered by the provider technologies (e.g., VirtualBox, VMWare, etc.). If the providers can't do synchronization on a per-file basis, then Vagrant can't either. Vagrant can also use [NFS](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/synced-folders/nfs.html), [RSync](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/synced-folders/rsync.html), or [SMB](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/synced-folders/smb.html) for file synchronization. However, [looking at the code](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/tree/master/plugins/synced_folders), it would appear that each expects the per-folder paradigm.

Another possibility is to use one of the [provisioning](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/provisioning/index.html) options to selectively synchronize the appropriate file(s). If you want to take the easy way out you could use the [shell provisioner](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/provisioning/shell.html) to just copy the file you need. For something more interesting, [this](http://www.erikaheidi.com/blog/a-beginners-guide-to-vagrant-part-2-provisioning-and-puppet) is a reasonable guide to getting started with [Puppet](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/provisioning/puppet_apply.html) in Vagrant, and you might be interested in the puppet [`file` Type](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/latest/type.html#file).

Answer (score 0):

As [Benjamin Mosior explained](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29419463), you can only synchronise a whole folder.

As a workaround, I ended up synchronising the whole folder to a temporary folder and in a later step creating a symlink where I need it to the single file inside this temporary folder.